# Access id in controller from table in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

Using Zf2 I want to access an id from a table in controller by writing the following:

```
$pname => $this->getProvincesTable()->fetch_province($pid);
```

But it gives me object of Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet, when I run the foreachloop as

```
foreach($pname as $p)
{  
echo $this->escapeHtml($p->id); 
}
```

in view: 
It gives me the id but I want to access the id in controller.

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you're using the TableGateway to fetch_province?

If you're returning a ResultSet (ie a collection of items) you can get a single row/entry like this:

```
$rowset => $this->getProvincesTable()->fetch_province($pid);
$myItem = $rowset->current();
$myItem->id; // do something with it here..
```

This will give you an array / ArrayObject which you can then access to get your Id.

You could do this inside your TableGateway method so you only get one entry back every time if indeed you are trying to get a single entry, or if you sometimes expect multiple items you can iterate over them or use the current() method above.

If you post some more of your code (specifically fetch_province) I could advise a little better.

For example;

If you always want 1 item back from this method using a primary key you could do something like this inside fetch_province:

```
$results = $table->select(array('id' => $id));

if(count($results) != 1) {
    // something went wrong, 
    // throw exception here or what ever
}

$row = $results->current();

return $row; // now u always get back your single item
```